# Android onTouch refresh rate

Tags: android

I am using 
    `onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)`
as a game input. It returns `false` so it is not handled. On my HTC HD2 running 4.0.4 this is enough to let the player walk fast enough (e.g. to jump off over obstacles). However my new HTC One S seems to slow in processing it when I only touch, when I swipe the time between two onTouch-Events is much faster. 
Is there a way to set the refresh rate of the onTouch Listener? Or do you have other solutions for controlling the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could don't rely on refresh rate, but save time difference (dt) between two updates and calculate speed according to elapsed time.