# Do some action while finger down

Tags: android, touch

I already asked this question but at that time I tought that the refresh time between to onTouch Events is my problem [Android onTouch refresh rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979304/android-ontouch-refresh-rate) . But it isn't. So again my problem:
I need a Sprite moving left/right/up while my finger is touching the display. So my onTouchEvent return true. But this works only if my finger swipes a bit or if the touchscreen drivers are so worse that it jitters so much what is detected as finger movement. 
I tought of a solution with Threads. So I start a Thread which is moving the player, which is interrupted when the finger is lifted. But maybe there is a better way to do that?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    ...
if (me.getY() < getHeight() / 2) {
    return doAction(0);
} else if (me.getX() >= getWidth() / 2)
    return doAction(2);
else if (me.getX() < getWidth() / 2)
    return doAction(1);
//doAction returns TRUE
...
```

}

Comment: pass the motion event to gesture detector it will give the method and movement velocity to monitor and react accordingly

Comment: The methods of the GestureDetector are triggered only once ...

Comment: yes it did but you can manage to get it work

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how I should use this for my project. Do you have an example for me?

Comment: this this could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I managed it with Threads. Here is a part of doAction.

```
if (event == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            movePlayer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                        if (main.player.x > 5
                                && now.getLevel()[playerXsc][playerYsc] == Level.FLAG_SKY
                                && now.getLevel()[playerXsc][playerY2sc] == Level.FLAG_SKY) {
                            main.player.x -= 4;
                        } else if (main.player.x <= 5 && now instanceof L9)
                            main.player.x = aspectX * 19;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) { break; }
                    }
                }
            };
            movePlayer.start();
        } else if (event == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.e("ui", "mpt interrupt");
            movePlayer.interrupt();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);    
                    finish();
                    return true;
                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                 //work u want to do etc ..use all the events like this 
}


        b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_back);    
        return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your doAction method is non-trivial then this will cause lag as future touch events will 'buffer' up awaiting a response from this onTouchEvent handler. Also, are you using

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
       // Changes to UI here...
    }
});
```

more info: [Activity.runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: doAction sets only 2 ints of the player object. It does not affect the UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.StudyWebview);   
detector = new GestureDetector(this, this); 
WebView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

please implements OnGestureListener and use its call back method

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float arg3) {
    float dX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
    float dY = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
    // check is all completed or return with some condition
    if (Math.abs(dY) < SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(velocityX) >= SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dX) >= SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
        // logic for left and right
        if (dX < 0) {

        }

        else if (dX > 0) {

        }
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

    return false;
}
```

Comment: if using this way if problem is not solved pleas post more detail about what you actually want to implement with it ......... and what result you are expecting

Comment: I don't want to swipe. I divided the screen in to three parts. The interact like buttons. One is for jumping, one for walking right and the other for walking left (doAction is triggered). Now while my finger touches down the screen the player should walk left/right according to where the touch happened and should stop when my finger lifts up.

Comment: I will write the code for this in free time and will post you soon if you can wait .............